# Force downloading in php

Tags: php, header, download

I am trying to create a force-download page to prevent browsers from opening files that should be downloaded. The problem is that the downloaded file has 0 bytes and thus is unusable. What is wrong with my code?

```
$file = "http://gh0stsec.zxq.net/background1.jpg";
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
@readfile($file);
exit();
```

Comment: `application/force-download` is not a real MIME type. It's retarded. That's not what triggers the download. It's `Content-Dispositon` only. Adding an invalid MIME type is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check:

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
```

I think it should be:

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved it right away. I have no idea how I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have an issue with `filesize` since it's not a local file (if it is, use a relative path).  `Content-Type` headers are always a little weird for me, but in all of the examples I read, `force-download` was always a fallback.  Anyways, I did this and it seemed to work:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('http://gh0stsec.zxq.net/background1.jpg');

if ($file) 
{

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=background1.jpg');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();

    echo $file;
} 
else   
{
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```